# UIButton inside a UIView not responding to gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I have a UIView with a UIButton inside it but the button does not recognise gestures

Any ideas why? I have tried using the solutions in the questions related to this but have not succeeded.

The whole class code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

public class HUDView: UIView , UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    var stopwatch: StopwatchView
    var gamePoints: CounterLabelView

     var hintButton: UIButton!

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Never call this... Use init(frame:)")
    }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.stopwatch = StopwatchView(frame: CGRect(x: ScreenWidth/2 - 150, y: 0, width: 300, height: 100))
        self.stopwatch.setSecondsRemaining(0)

        self.gamePoints = CounterLabelView(font: FontHUD!, frame: CGRect(x: ScreenWidth - 200, y: 30, width: 320, height: 70))
        gamePoints.textColor = UIColor.black
        gamePoints.value = 0

        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.addSubview(gamePoints)
        let pointsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: ScreenWidth - 340, y: 30, width: 140, height: 70))
        pointsLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        pointsLabel.font = FontHUD
        pointsLabel.text = " Points:"
        self.addSubview(pointsLabel)

        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.addSubview(self.stopwatch)

        //load the button image
        let hintButtonImage = UIImage(named: "btn")!

        //the help button
        self.hintButton = UIButton()
      //  hintButton.perform(#selector(HUDView.s))
        hintButton.setTitle("Hint!", for:.normal)
        hintButton.titleLabel?.font = lHud
        hintButton.setBackgroundImage(hintButtonImage, for: .normal)
        hintButton.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 30, width: hintButtonImage.size.width, height: hintButtonImage.size.height)

       // hintButton.center = self.center
        //50, 30, hintButtonImage.size.width, hintButtonImage.size.height
        hintButton.alpha = 1.0
        hintButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.addSubview(hintButton)

    //    hintButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tapButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        let g = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.h(_:)))
        g.delegate = self
        hintButton.addGestureRecognizer(g)
    }

    func h(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("hey!")
        fatalError()
    }

}
```

Comment: why you are not dircetly used addtarget instead of gesture

Comment: it doesn't work aswell @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Show the code by which you create your HUDView and put it into the interface. That is the code that is at fault.

Comment: Are you sure that `hintButton` is inside the bounds of the `HUDView`?

Comment: Also it is definitely silly to add a tap gesture recognizer to a button. But that is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: check teh frame of your button `hintButton.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 30, width: hintButtonImage.size.width, height: hintButtonImage.size.height)`, the reason `hintButtonImage.` not defined

Comment: @matt updateddd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in line `self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

You are adding button as a `subview` to `HUDView`. The button tap will not work because the parent view ie:`HUDView` has user interaction disabled and so the user interaction of all the `subViews` will be disabled.
Make  the changes as `self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` it will work.